# make faster using -k faster than make?

Tags: makefile

why does 
`make -k -j4 ;make -k -j4;make;`
appear to be faster than `make -j4` ? 
I am using it to compile c++ and It appears to be faster because it does the linking all in one go but I am not sure does anyone know why ?

Comment: Why settle for "appears to be"?  Why not just script it and use `time` to determine if it really is, or not?  Run it a few times each way and take the average.  I would be very surprised if there were any difference but as others have said below a lot depends on whether the build is succeeding or failing.  If it's succeeding then running make multiple times is obviously going to be slower than running it once (assuming the same `-j` flags).  If it's failing then it shouldn't matter how many times you run it.

Comment: I believe that if one thread has to wait for another thread to finish in order to perform the linking then this would slow it down. but if the -k option is used I think it would not wait for the other thread it would simply carry on compiling another file. and then the second iteration would link it because the other thread had compiled the object the first thread was dependant on

Comment: Again, test and you'll see the answer to timing.  However, what you say here is not true.  The `-k` flag controls exactly one thing: if make detects that a recipe failed, does it keep building more targets?  Or does it stop?  `-k` is not involved in deciding what to wait for or not wait for.  If you have no failed recipes then there is zero difference between with `-k` and without `-k`.  Plus just to be clear, there are no threads in make.  It just forks multiple recipes to run as children in parallel: make itself is single-threaded.

Comment: I am running a test right now it will take a good while to build twice. +1 for the info about make I thought it was threaded not multiprocessor. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do know what the `-k` flag does? It tells `make` to try and keep going even in the case of errors. That means it will probably continue even when some files fails to build because of dependencies not being built yet (which can happen when you use the `-j` flag). The second invocation of `make` does a second attempt to build files, and the third finishes up.

The invocation without `-k` will stop as soon as there is an error, making you do it again, maybe multiple times. This will definitely *feel* that it takes a longer time, and probably do take longer time as well as it needs user interactions.

Answer (score 1):

The flag `-k` instructs `make` to keep going doing its stuff even in case of errors. `-j4` instructs `make` to start four processes at the same time when possible for unrelated targets.

In case your `make` operation is successful, i.e. no error occurs, then the second and third calls to `make`, whatever the arguments you pass should report a simple 'Nothing to do'.

I've to suggest this as a time illusion.